# Strange JavaScript Object syntax

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, javascript-objects

I recently came accross this in a Library called WebApp.net:

```
var $h = {
    get HEAD() { return 0 },
    get BACK() { return 1 },
    get HOME() { return 2 },
    get LEFT() { return 3 },
    get RIGHT() { return 4 },
    get TITLE() { return 5 }
};
var $d = {
    get L2R() { return +1 },
    get R2L() { return -1 }
};
```

I'm familar with JS, but this seems to make no sense. Chrome does interpret this as Object with $h.HEAD and the others set as numbers which come after the return. Additionally, something like getters are part of $h, too.

Can anybody give me more info about this? IE cannot interpret this, so I have to make an equivalent to this.

Comment: It's an object containing [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). Works also in IE>8.

Comment: @Teemu: make it an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've found [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

With a getter you can execute a function, when you're reading a property of an object. Also it is a way to give some protection to object properties,  you can't change the value of a getter directly.

Getters and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) are implemented also in IE since IE9.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I was surprised to came accross such a "modern" feature in such an old code. My IE problem was because of compat mode in IE11 wich is mostly like IE8. There it's not available.

Comment: @sja I don't know, how old WebApp.net is, but in FF getters and setters are supported since 2.0, which has been released in 2006.